# How to find the relative Text Size

Tags: java, android, algorithm, math, android-canvas

I am trying to draw text on images with varying sizes.  The image is displayed in an `ImageView` and then drawn on the `Canvas`.  While the `Canvas` retains the image's original height and width, the image does appear a lot smaller in the `ImageView` so this makes selecting an appropriate text size for the `Canvas` very tedious, as the `ImageView` gives a false perception of how the text will appear on the image.

To come across this problem, I decided to use cross-multiplication to find an appropriate text size for the text on `Canvas`, which is suppose to appear on the `Canvas` as it does on the `ImageView`.  Here is my attempt:

```
textSize = topTextView.getTextSize();
imageViewArea = ((img.getWidth()) * (img.getHeight()));
canvasArea = ((canvas.getWidth()) * (canvas.getHeight()));
x = (((textSize)/(imageViewArea)) * (canvasArea));
```

The first line gets the size of the text that appears on the `ImageView`.  The 2nd and 3rd lines compute the area of the `ImageView` and the `Canvas`.  The third line basically puts it all together and (ideally) outputs a float value that is to be the size of the text drawn on the `Canvas`.

However, it isn't close to how it should be.  The text is unintelligible when its drawn on small images.  Thin and ugly when its drawn on mid-size images.  Basically, it looks nothing like in the preview.

My assumption is:  Cross-Multiplication is not the way to go.

Any suggestions?

```
public Bitmap createMeme(ImageView img){
        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = ((BitmapDrawable) img.getDrawable());
        Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
        Bitmap mutableBitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

        String topText = topTextView.getText().toString();
        String bottomText = bottomTextView.getText().toString();

        topText = topText.toUpperCase();
        bottomText = bottomText.toUpperCase();

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mutableBitmap);

        TextPaint topFillPaint = new TextPaint();
        TextPaint bottomFillPaint = new TextPaint();

        TextPaint topStrokePaint = new TextPaint();
        TextPaint bottomStrokePaint = new TextPaint();

        Typeface typeface = getResources().getFont(R.font.impact);

        textSize = topTextView.getTextSize();
        imageViewArea = ((img.getWidth()) * (img.getHeight()));
        canvasArea = ((canvas.getWidth()) * (canvas.getHeight()));
        val = textSize * sqrt(canvasArea / imageViewArea);
        x = (float)val;

        topFillPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        topFillPaint.setTextSize(x);
        topFillPaint.setTypeface(typeface);

        topStrokePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        topStrokePaint.setStrokeWidth(4);
        topStrokePaint.setTextSize(x);
        topStrokePaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        topStrokePaint.setTypeface(typeface);

        bottomFillPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        bottomFillPaint.setTextSize(x);
        bottomFillPaint.setTypeface(typeface);

        bottomStrokePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        bottomStrokePaint.setStrokeWidth(4);
        bottomStrokePaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        bottomStrokePaint.setTextSize(x);
        bottomStrokePaint.setTypeface(typeface);

        StaticLayout topFillLayout = new StaticLayout(topText, topFillPaint, canvas.getWidth(), Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER,
                0.8f, 0.0f, false);
        StaticLayout topStrokeLayout = new StaticLayout(topText, topStrokePaint, canvas.getWidth(), Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER,
                0.8f, 0.0f, false);
        StaticLayout bottomFillLayout = new StaticLayout(bottomText, bottomFillPaint, canvas.getWidth(), Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER,
                0.8f, 0.0f, false);
        StaticLayout bottomStrokeLayout = new StaticLayout(bottomText, bottomStrokePaint, canvas.getWidth(), Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER,
                0.8f, 0.0f, false);


        topFillLayout.draw(canvas);

        topStrokeLayout.draw(canvas);

        canvas.translate(0, canvas.getHeight() - 50);
        bottomFillLayout.draw(canvas);

        bottomStrokeLayout.draw(canvas);

        return mutableBitmap;
    }
```

**OUTPUT**

So I've uploaded 4 images with different dimensions to see what the text size is for each of them.  Here are my findings:

1. `274 x 184` topTextSize: 0, bottomTextSize: 0
2. `3704 x 2469` topTextSize: 237.58, bottomTextSize: 237.58
3. `640 x 480` topTextSize: 0, bottomTextSize: 0
4. `2560 x 1920` topTextSize: 168, bottomTextSize: 168

For `2` and `4`, only the top text shows on the bitmap

For example, here are the values for the image with dimensions `274 x 184`:

```
textSize = 168
imageViewArea = 1728000
canvasArea = 50416
x = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ratio that you calculate is a ratio of areas, not the ratio of lengths. If you scale the image by 2 along each side, you will get an area ratio of 4 (or 1/4, depending on the direction that you consider). The font size should be a length, therefore you should use a length ratio.

If you know that the scaling is uniform (height is scaled equally as width), simply calculate the ratios based on either width or height (not the areas). If it is not, you would need a text rendering method that can stretch the font in one direction. If you want to use some kind of average font size that preserves the area ratio, simply use `x = textSize * sqrt(canvasArea / imageViewArea)`.

Off-topic comment: You have a lot of unnecessary parentheses in your code snippet. Personally, I think that this make reading the code more difficult. I would therefore advise to remove unnecessary parentheses (unless they are used intentionally to convey a certain meaning).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190677/discussion-on-answer-by-nico-schertler-how-to-find-the-relative-text-size).